# how to get rid of unwanted lines? while loop?

Tags: bash, grep

I have wrote this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filter(){

grep -Ev "INFO" /app/me/logs/$1

}

filter "$1" > /app/me/logs/${1}.filtered

cat /app/me/logs/${1}.filtered
```

so what it does is that it eliminates all the lines that has the word INFO in it. But at the same time it is outputting the following:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Sep 27, 2016 2:55:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Sep 27, 2016 2:55:09 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Sep 27, 2016 2:55:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
16:53:05,024 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ORA-00001: unique constraint (LIFERAY.IX_57D82B06) violated_ [Sanitized]
16:53:05,028 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ORA-00001: unique constraint (LIFERAY.IX_57D82B06) violated_ [Sanitized]
16:53:05,123 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][ParallelDestination:72] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={JOB_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, EXCEPTIONS_MAX_SIZE=0, GROUP_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, JOB_STATE=com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.JobState@3c5ee4ef, companyId=0, MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, RECEIVER_KEY=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener.com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, MESSAGE_LISTENER_UUID=6f44c739-1146-447a-893d-16099898c2ff}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor262.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:251)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.fetchByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5333)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.fetchByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5245)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.findByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5205)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.getCompanyGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:1091)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

As you can see it works fine, but there is some unwatned lines at the top that do not contain words such as "ERROR|FATAL|WARN". I dont need these lines but at the same time i want the lines that are indented and the line before it. i want it to look something like:

```
16:53:05,024 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ORA-00001: unique constraint (LIFERAY.IX_57D82B06) violated_ [Sanitized]
16:53:05,028 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] ORA-00001: unique constraint (LIFERAY.IX_57D82B06) violated_ [Sanitized]
16:53:05,123 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-6][ParallelDestination:72] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=null, values={JOB_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, EXCEPTIONS_MAX_SIZE=0, GROUP_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, DESTINATION_NAME=liferay/scheduler_dispatch, JOB_STATE=com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.JobState@3c5ee4ef, companyId=0, MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, RECEIVER_KEY=com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener.com.liferay.portlet.trash.messaging.CheckEntryMessageListener, MESSAGE_LISTENER_UUID=6f44c739-1146-447a-893d-16099898c2ff}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor262.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler.messaging.SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.receive(SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper.java:76)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.impl.BasePersistenceImpl.processException(BasePersistenceImpl.java:251)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.fetchByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5333)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.fetchByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5245)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.GroupPersistenceImpl.findByC_C_C(GroupPersistenceImpl.java:5205)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.getCompanyGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:1091)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Any help?
Thanks,

Comment: I thought about doing a while loop to read every line that when it reaches a line with indentation it greps it and the line before it (providing the line before it is not indented). But i don't know how to write this in code.

Comment: grep -B1 " at " ?

Comment: but that eliminates the lines with the word "ERROR" in them.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out all lines, up to the first line beginning with a digit, use GNU `sed` like this:

```
sed '1,/^[0-9]/{/^[0-9]/!d}' logfile
```

This `sed` editing script will apply `/^[0-9]/!d`, i.e. "delete all lines not starting with a digit", to all lines in the range 1 to the first line beginning with a digit (`1,/^[0-9]/`), inclusively.

To additionally filter out any INFO line:

```
sed -e '1,/^[0-9]/{/^[0-9]/!d}' -e '/INFO/d' logfile
```

So your script becomes

```
#!/bin/bash

function filter {
    sed -e '1,/^[0-9]/{/^[0-9]/!d}' -e '/INFO/d'
}

filter <"/app/me/logs/$1" >"/app/me/logs/$1.filtered"
```

Notice too that I made the `filter` function agnostic of filenames or paths. Its only purpose is to take an input stream and output a filtered stream.

Answer (score -1):

Why not the following:

```
grep -Ev "INFO|SLF4J|201[0-9]
```

Comment: That works but some files have lines that start with different codes such as CDM6K and such. I appreciate your help though!